# Creating & controlling a nest of Parent divs in Grid 960

Tags: html, css, media-queries, 960.gs

**Here's the layout I'm trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/qeDs3/44/**

I mocked it up on Indesign using Grid_960 templates: http://designobvio.us/dov2/Homepage1.pdf

Here are the divs I cannot make parents out of http://designobvio.us/dov2/Homepage1Encapulate.pdf

Through trial an error, grid 960 seems forces you to use the class `container_12` in conjunction to `.grid_12` as the parent tag.

Here's another full example: http://designobvio.us/dov2/index.html
*How can i get gChild to be the parent*

Heres paired down example: http://designobvio.us/dov2/index2.html
I'm trying to get the header tag to be the parent of its contents.

Does my layout not cooperate with grid960?  Am I totally missing something stupid?  Does it require a hack?  If you need any clarification of anything I'll be right here and will response ASAP.
Thanks

**Update** The reason I'm trying to do this is so that I may gain control of those parent divs for ease of media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After EXTENSIVE research (lol) I've finally solved this problem.

Grid 960 has 2 extra classes which simply remove margins left and right named **alpha & omega**.  I've never bothered learning the purpose/theory of these because I was dumb.  The purpose of these classes are exactly what I was curious to, "nesting grids within grids;" thus allowing me to clear the float and control the parent div's that dont abide by the 12 column standard.

I hope someday this question/answer helps some other fool that refuses to read documentation.